# How to skip first parameter in a string of a given css property?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an html DOM object at `element.style.backgroundSize` and i can pass an argument to it like "100px 100px" meaning width and height.

If i skip a parameter, and send it just one argument, like "100px" it will just interpret width.

**How to pass it only height parameter?**

"auto 100px" malfunction.

Comment: Do you mean `backgroundSize`? What do you mean "malfunction"

Comment: it gives backgroundSize wrong dimensions

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this issue?

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Your question does not really make sense. The behavior of that property, when only one length value is assigned, is _specified_. If you do not want that behavior - then you simply _don’t_ want to assign only one value in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The `background-size` property accepts values in the form `auto 100px`, [as outlined on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#syntax). To specify the required `background-size` with JavaScript, you could do the following:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div');

/* Apply background size with specified height only */
element.style.backgroundSize = `auto 100px`;
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  /* Image's natural dimensions larger than 100px */
  background:url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x350) no-repeat red center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```